# Гугл таблица. Убрать время из даты

Tags: google-spreadsheet, макрос, редактор-текста

Нужен макрос для преобразования даты и времени только в дату.

При заполнении таблицы через форму (дата заполнения формы) ответ появляется следующего вида: 12-12-2022 16:23:45. Мне для корректной работы других формул нужна только дата, без времени.

Возможно ли составить макрос, который будет удалять 10 знаков справа в выбранной ячейке?

Спасибо.

Comment: И в чём проблема? В попытке усложнить задачу из-за непонимания предмета? 1) Открываем таблицу. 2) Идём в макросы: меню "Расширения/Макросы/Записать макрос". 3) Выделяем ячейку или колонку с "неправильными" датами и переходим в меню "Формат/Числа/Дата" и оно само всё отрабатывает как надо. Если нужно, то можно сделать и "Пользовательский" формат. 4) Сохраняем макрос и пользуемся в своё удовольствие. А то ишь чего надумали: удалять 10 знаков

Comment: Формат он меняет, но содержание ячейки нет. Время из-за смены формата отображения никуда не исчезает.

Comment: а почему вы тогда не указали эту информацию в посте: какой формат на выходе вам нужен? Формат "Дата", он и есть — дата. Нужен текстовый? Так добавьте в макрос ещё одно действие: "Формат/Числа/Обычный текст".

Comment: Мне не нужен формат отображения. Он не меняет содержимое. Нужно изменить 12-12-2022 16:13:28 на 12-12-2022. Дата заполнения формы добавляется автоматически таким видом. И в последующих формулах она не работает. Если руками убираю дату, всё ок. Но я не могу менять по 50 дат в день.

Comment: Похоже вы меня не понимаете. Если ваша формула неправильно считает даты, то проблема с формулой. Ну да ладно. Пойдём другим путём, как вы озвучили: заменой текста.  1) идём в макросы и стартуем запись. 2) выделяем ячейку или диапазон с датами 3) находим меню "Правка/Найти и заменить", а в появившемся окошке чекаем галочку "Поиск с использованием регулярных выражений" в поле "Найти" вставляем следующую последовательность —  `\s\d+:\d+:\d+`  4) нажимаем кнопку "Заменить все". 5) останавливаем запись макроса.  ГОТОВО.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Используйте доп. столбец с формулой `=ЦЕЛОЕ(дата+время)` - и не нужен макрос.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел для себя след вариант, заходим в формат меняем на дата, затем еще раз меняем на обычный тест. Таким образом, удаляется время с столбце.